# How to change background every day?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a webpage and I would like to change the background to a different one every day. I have 4 images in total so I would like to cycle through them. How can I do that?

Edit: According to the comments, it looks like I can't do this with HTML and CSS alone so I would have to use another language. How can I do that?

Here's the code of my CSS and HTML respectively:

```css
.main-section .main-division {
  background: url(../images/background-1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main-section">
        <div class="main-division">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="main-cover" >
                 CONTENT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With JavaScript. Neither CSS nor HTML have any concept of time

Comment: You will have to use a scripting language. PHP, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: How many images do you have? 365?:)

Comment: I have 4 pictures. I would like to cycle through them and repeat. How can I do that with Javascript or any other language?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to make it work using a combination of the response from @Rana and @Twisty

Here's the resulting code:

```js
//Code on change-background.js

$(function() {
  var backgrounds = [
    "../images/background-1.jpg",
    "../images/background-2.jpg",
    "../images/background-3.jpg",
    "../images/background-4.jpg"
  ];

  var dt = new Date();
  var index = dt.getDay() % 4;

  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgrounds[index] + ")";
});
```

```css
.main-section .main-division {
  background: url(../images/background-1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main-section">
        <div class="main-division">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="main-cover" >
                 CONTENT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="js/change-background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var backgrounds = [
    "../images/background-1.jpg",
    "../images/background-2.jpg",
    "../images/background-3.jpg",
    "../images/background-4.jpg"
  ];

  var dt = new Date();
  var index = dt.getDay() % 4;

  $(".main-section .main-division").css("background-image", "url(" + backgrounds[index] + ")");
});
```

```css
.main-section .main-division {
  background: url(../images/background-1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main-section">
  <div class="main-division">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main-cover">
        CONTENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Using an array, you can store (or collect) the image paths. You can pick an Index based on the Day of the Week (0 - 6) and use the Modulus operator to help ensure the the `index` is always correct or in scope.

Comment: I added this but the background image doesn't keep the properties from the CSS

Comment: @Darknicks made a minor update to use `background-image` specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a bit of Javascript. The following snippet will display a different colour each day of the week:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.change-my-colour');
/* .change this to .main-division in your code ^^^ */
let date = new Date();

switch(date.getDay()) { /* use date.getDate() instead for days of the month */
  case 0: /* Sunday */
    element.style.background = "red";
    break;
  case 1: /* Monday */
    element.style.background = "orange";
    break;
  case 2: /* Tuesday */
    element.style.background = "yellow";
    break;
  /* etc... */
  default:
    break;
}
```

```css
.change-my-colour {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue; /* default value */
}
```

```html
<div class="change-my-colour"></div>
```

Change the colours above to the images you would like to display on each day (using the same form as in your css but wrapped in quotes).

Also if you're unfamiliar with Javascript the easiest way to include it in your website is using a [script](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp) tag.

Answer (score -2):

> Use `setInterval(backgroundChange, 86400000);` this way the function `backgroundChange` will run in an interval of every 24hr(=86400000ms).
> You can then define a function `backgroundChange()` which change background .

You can try different approach by using week days or date of month as input value
You can use `if elseIf` loops like in below snippet :

```js
backgroundImages = ['urlImage1', 'urlImage2', 'urlImage3', 'urlImage4'];

var date = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();

if (dayOfWeek == "0") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek] + ")";
} else if (dayOfWeek == "1") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek] + ")";
} else if (dayOfWeek == "2") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek] + ")";
} else if (dayOfWeek == "3") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek] + ")";
} else if (dayOfWeek == "4") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek - 4] + ")";
} else if (dayOfWeek == "5") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek - 4] + ")";
} else if (dayOfWeek == "6") {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImages[dayOfWeek - 4] + ")";
} else {
  document.querySelector('.main-division').style.backgroundImage = "url(somebackup-image)";
}
```

```css
.main-section .main-division {
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="main-division">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-cover">
          CONTENT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="If_JS_is_present_in_file_use_src_else_simply_write_inside_this_tag"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How or where would I add this code?

Comment: Use it where you are defining background as image in JS

Comment: Unless you are running the website for a day straight this will only display whatever you set as the initial background, and if you randomize the initial background it will be change the background every time you reload the site.

Comment: I define the background in CSS. Can you add JavaScript in CSS? Or would I have to put that in the HTML header?

Comment: @Bdeering you are right I forget about that , can making cookie be the solution for this or server side reference is better for background image url

Comment: As told by @Darknicks it will not work unless system is open for `24hr` and reset on each reload , lets wait for @Bdeering response

Comment: @Rana You could use local storage to do something like this, but it would be more complicated than necessary for this particular problem imo.