# How can I get my quotes to change every day

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my quotes to change every single day, but when I run it, it just stays on one quote. What fixes or changes can I make to get my quote to repeat every single day?

Here is the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quote</title>

    <style>

        .widget {
            padding: 5px 5px ;
            color: #C93F79;
            text-align: center;
                max-width: 95%;
            margin: auto;
            font-variant-caps: petite-caps;
            font-size: 2em;

        }

        div {
             width: 95%;
             min-height: 100px;

            background:
                linear-gradient(to right,  pink 4px, transparent 4px) 0 0,
                linear-gradient(to right, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 0 100%,
                linear-gradient(to left, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 100% 0,
                linear-gradient(to left, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 100% 100%,
                linear-gradient(to bottom, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 0 0,
                linear-gradient(to bottom, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 100% 0,
                linear-gradient(to top, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 0 100%,
                linear-gradient(to top, pink 4px, transparent 4px) 100% 100%;

            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 20px 20px;
}

     
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="widget" id="widget"></div>


<script>

quotes=[
"Self-care is not a luxury; it's a necessity.",
"I am in competition with no one. I have no desire to play the game of being better than anyone. I am simply trying to be better than the person I was yesterday.",
"How you care for yourself is how you care for the world.",
"Every day it gets a little easier... But you gotta do it every day—that's the hard part. But it does get easier.",
"Displicine is the highest form of self-care",
"How you spend your time .",
"Most people overestimate what they can do in one year and underestimate what they can do in ten years.",
"A goal without a plan is just a wish.",
"Every second counts",
"There aint nothing but today.",
"The more you fulfill your goals, the more you learn to trust yourself.",
"Every decision you make casts a vote for the person you want to be.",
"Twenty years from now, you will be more disappointed by the things that you didn't do than by the ones you did do. So throw off the bowlines. Sail away from the safe harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails. Explore. Dream. Discover.",
];

const INTERVAL = 86400000;

function dispalyQuote(){

    document.getElementById('widget').innerHTML =quotes[0];
    quotes.forEach((quote, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('widget').innerHTML =quote;
        }, i * INTERVAL);  
    });
    }

    function dispalyWidget() {
        dispalyQuote();
        setTimeout(dispalyWidget, quotes.length*INTERVAL);
    }
    dispalyWidget()

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How it would work is that each every 24 hours the code would move onto the quote until it's back at the first quote and then it repeats on and on.

Comment: That code's running in your users' browsers, and restarts every time they load the page. Maybe you could pick based on a number of days since a fixed day (e.g. today).

Comment: Chiming in with jonrsharpe: if you would generate the message server-side you can send a different message everyday. Since you implemented it browser-side: check the date and display the appropriate message for that date.  You will need to add some logic, but start by getting the current date (or day of the week) and work from thereon. https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-get-day-of-the-week-in-javascript-using-getday#:~:text=The%20getDay()%20returns%20a,represents%20Monday%2C%20and%20so%20on.

Comment: I suggest to use ```Math.random()```, since you have no *counter* to check if this day(quote[0]) is not today(quote[1]).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change background every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259622/how-to-change-background-every-day)

Comment: @Klaassiek I am new to html so I'm trying to imagine what that would look like, would the date logic be at the top, and then for each quote I'd assign a day?

Answer (score -3):

try changing the INTERVAL = 86400

Comment: I don't see how reducing the time from 24 hours to 86,4 seconds  would solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).